# jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError for variables passing to python function from Flask template

Tags: flask, jinja2

I am getting this error `jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'values' is undefined`. The simple code which I am using with reference from the Flask website http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/templating/ is below:

```
@app.context_processor
def utility_processor():
    def format_price(amount, currency=u'€'):
        return u'{0:.2f}{1}'.format(float(amount), currency)
    return dict(format_price=format_price)

@app.route("/file_t")
def file_t():

    return render_template('DB.html')


@app.route("/file_ttt", methods=['POST'])
def file_ttt():

    if request.method == 'POST':
        bMultyTest_plot = request.values.get("bMultyTest_plot")
        print(bMultyTest_plot)

        return jsonify({'result': 'success', 'value': 0.44})
```

And the html template code below:

```
<button type="button" onclick="visualize()">Visualize</button>
<div id='here'></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function visualize()
    {
        req = $.ajax({
            url : "/file_ttt",
            type: "POST",
            data: {"bMultyTest_plot": true}
        })

        req.done(function(data) {
            var values = data.value;
             document.getElementById("here").innerHTML ="{{format_price(values)}}";
        });
    }   
</script>
```

Instead of the variable values, if I pass a float value, the function works. like:

```
 document.getElementById("here").innerHTML ="{{format_price(0.33)}}";
```

but with a variable i am getting the below error:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML ="{{format_price(values)}}";
File "<ipython-input-138-4e2a0498745e>", line 17, in format_price
return u'{0:.2f}{1}'.format(float(amount), currency)
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'values' is undefined
10.45.65.219 - - [19/Mar/2019 09:56:12] "GET /file_t HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your template expects `values` variable, but you don't provide it when calling the `render_template` function in `file_t`. You need to provide it like this:

```
return render_template('DB.html', values=values)
```

See [the documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#rendering-templates) for more information.

Comment: How to send the variable values to the context_processor function using {{format_price(values)}} ? values is what I get back from the Flask python script and i need to pass this to the function format_price.

Comment: I can't see where you actually get the `values` value anywhere in your code. However, I'm pretty sure you don't need to _send the variable values to the context_processor function_. What I understand you really need is to pass `values` from your view function to the template and then format it for display using `format_price` function. In that case, it's better to use [filter](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/templating/#registering-filters) instead of context processor for `format_price` and supply `values` in `render_template`.